# Что означает символ @ в javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

***Что означает символ @ в javascript/jQuery?***

```
 // Метод создает структуру товара.
  @param jQuerySelector
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это часть комментария из [JSDoc](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc), описывает параметр который передается в метод.

Пример из wiki:

```
/**
 * Создает экземпляр Circle.
 *
 * @constructor
 * @this  {Circle}
 * @param {number} r - Радиус окружности.
 */
function Circle(r) {
    /** @private */
    this.radius = r;

    /** @private */
    this.circumference = 2 * Math.PI * r;
}
```

Comment: Это не javadoc, а [jsdoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc), раз уж речь идёт о javascript.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf опечатался

Comment: Значит это документация? И на работу кода не влияет?

Comment: @Pavel нет, но лучше её писать чтобы другим разработчикам было проще работать с вашим кодом, да и вам тоже спустя время.

Comment: а на работу кода не влияет?

Comment: @Pavel соблюдение синтаксиса документации необходимо для того, чтобы программы, такие как IDE, могли её понимать и предлагать умное автодополнение/навигацию по вашему коду. Кроме того из этих комментариев можно сгенерировать нечто вроде вики. Очень удобная штука! ;)